# Running flask app with docker & kubernetes

Tags: docker, flask, kubernetes

The Flask docs [say](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/#deployment):

> While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and by default serves only one request at a time.

I'll be running my flask app in a docker container under kubernetes.

Am I right in thinking that the above advice isn't relevant in my case, since I can just run multiple pods, and the fact that they're single-threaded isn't an issue (perhaps a benefit if anything)?

Comment: It still applies. Obviously you can horizontally scale the app out to 100's of instances of Flask with a LB in front, but that's pretty inefficient. Why not just put Flask behind gunicorn or something?

Comment: @johnharris85 I thought it was best practice to only have a single process running in a docker container. Is that not the case?

Comment: Gunicorn would be the only thing running? And then nginx in a different container in front of it?

Comment: @johnharris85 Yeah. But gunicorn would spawn multiple workers. I guess that's Ok.

Comment: Yep :) I mean, anything is 'OK' as long as it makes sense in your context, given your constraints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the number of clients that might connect with your servers at single time. You will be able to serve as much instances that you turn on (containers). Modern webservers today handles hundreds or thousands requests simultaneously.. if your clients are end users (so you are kind of website) and expected a lot of traffic - it won't be enough. If it for few requests, like another module in your system which connect to your webserver it might be enough. BTW check for WSGI before spinning up containers, it might solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah a bit more reading about Gunicorn has clarified the error in my thinking. Gunicorn can improve throughput over the naive blocking flask dev server. So it seems that I'll be better off running gunicorn in a container, and proxying requests to it with nginx to act as a buffer (since this is to serve a public API). Apparently the whole 'one process per container' thing is just a guideline.